# Having Dynamic evaluated when off screen

Tags: dynamic

As the title says, I want a cell containing the dynamic solution of a DAE-System to be available over the whole document. I use a lot of different Plots and Sliders scattered over the document and it is pretty annoying that after the cell scrolled off screen, the dynamic stuff stops working altogether (as this is the nature of `Dynamic` as the documentation explains it). If I copy `Dynamic[Solution]` and insert it all over the place everything works perfectly fine but does of course look unprofessional. Therefore I tried `DynamicWrapper["This is a text", Dynamic[Solution]]` to hide `Dynamic[Solution]` inside titles and texts that are scattered around anyway. This does however not work as I imagined it must.

If someone has an idea how to comfortably solve the issue I would be glad.

Edit: The system is a scale that works by compensation method; some code:

This is my variable called solution

```
solution = 
Dynamic[sol2 = 
Quiet[NDSolve[{d1'[t] == d2[t], 
d2'[t] == k*d1[t] + b*d2[t] + (ki*l)/\[Theta][t]*d3[t] + (l*g)/\[Theta][t]*
         (mersatz - mass[t, offset, Mass]), 
d3'[t] == -((ki*l)/L)*d2[t] - R/L*d3[t] + (U[t] + Uoffset)/L, 
U[t] == kP*U2[t] + kI*IntegralPart[t] + kD*U2'[t], 
U2[t] == -ks*l* d1[t],
D[IntegralPart[t], {t, 1}] == U2[t],
d1[0] == 0, d2[0] == 0, d1'[0] == 0, 
d2'[0] == (l*ki)/\[Theta][0]*Uoffset/R + (l*g)/\[Theta][0]*
          (mersatz - mass[0, offset, Mass]), 
  d3'[0] == 0, d3[0] == Uoffset/R , U[0] == 0, U2[0] == 0, 
  IntegralPart[0] == 0}, {d1, d2 , d3, U, U2, IntegralPart}, {t, 
  0, duration}
 ]]]
```

After that follows a big plot of the measured / calculated load on my scale

```
PlotWeight = 
Manipulate[
Quiet[Plot[{measuredweight[t] /. sol2, 
 If[referencew == 1, mass[t, offset, Mass], ""]} , {t, 0, 
 duration}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Darker[Green]}, 
ImageSize -> {1200, 400}, AspectRatio -> Full,  
ExclusionsStyle -> {Darker[Green], None}, 
AxesLabel -> {Style["time [s]", FontFamily -> font1], 
  Style["measured weight [kg]", FontFamily -> font1]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, duration}, If[scale == 1, Full, {0, scale}]}]],
Style["      +", 12]
, {{scale, 1, 
Rotate[Style["AxisScale", FontFamily -> font1, FontSize -> 12], 
 90 \[Degree] ]}, 0.01, 1, ControlType -> VerticalSlider}, 
Style["      -", 
12], {{referencew, 0, 
Style["activate weight reference", FontFamily -> font1, 
 FontSize -> 12]} , {0, 1}}, 
ControlPlacement -> {Left, Left, Left, Top}, Alignment -> Center ]
```

Other variables displayed in interactive Plots are current, voltage, angular velocity, angle, etc. All those are coming from the DAE that is fitted in solution (in the variable sol2 inside of solution).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A full picture in this [Pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/74966785/Preview%20of%20projekt7.pdf).

Comment: Why do you want it available when you can't see it? You have sliders but you can't see the solution, right?

Comment: In any case, there are alternatives. From scheduled tasks, to a notebook dynamic expression, to a dynamic docked cell. But I ask because probably there's a design issue here

Comment: The variable solution is used in Plots around the documents (with individual Sliders for individual plots) in the fashion: Plot[U[t] /.solution ...]

Comment: Then what about making solution be a function of the values set on the sliders?

Comment: The brackets of your last code block aren't balanced

Comment: I looked "docked cell" up in the documentation; did not knew it before and it looks pretty neat (especially for embedding my controls - you can see those in the pdf i linked right under the actual question). Since the documentation is quite brief on this functionality i am not sure how to implement it. Could you assist me with information on how to transform a cell of my existing document into such a docked cell?

Comment: You can run this `CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], DockedCells] = (Pause[3]; NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]])` and as soon as you evaluate you have 3 seconds to select the cell you want to get docked and wait for it >P

Comment: Now your second block of code ends in a comma?

Comment: It seems odd that `solution` as a variable defined here is `Dynamic[(*some stuff*)]` while the comments above suggest that `solution` is used in the form `Plot[U[t]/.solution...]`.  As Rojo says, there are many possible answers to the question, but I just don't feel I understand the question well enough to say which (if any) of them are appropriate for you.  Incidentally, an additional tool I would add to Rojo's list is the use of notebook-level `TaggingRules` to emulate notebook-level `DynamicModule` variables.  See the examples section of the `TaggingRules` docs for more info.

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation on my part: What I use for the plots is of course the variable sol2 inside of solution. I just gave another name to the whole dynamic expression (solution) to copy it several times to the document to be able to intermediately test the other elements of the layout. As suggested by Rojo I will use DockedCells for the control panel.

Comment: I often use SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookDynamicExpression :> (something here)], for different reasons when working with lengthy documents. Also, since I don't know when is the "enable dynamics" going to wake up (or when is the user going to enable them), I use it to make sure initialization of different variables and functions was made (if I put it on just one of the cells, it may be off screen at the time of the enable; if I put in all of them, it looks unprofessional): If[TrueQ[init == True], Null,some code here;init = True]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines copied from the documentation system seem to point at what you need to solve your problem:

> `FrontEndDynamicExpression -> Dynamic[expr]` causes the expression to
>   be tracked and updated in the usual way, except that `expr` is not
>   displayed anywhere.
>
> `FrontEndDynamicExpression` can be set using
>   `SetOptions[scope,FrontEndDynamicExpression->Dynamic[expr]]`, where
>   `scope` can be `$FrontEnd` or `$FrontEndSession`.

You may also consider using `CellDynamicExpression`.

In any case, `Dynamic` used without any `TrackedSymbols` specification is usually very inefficient as it will update much more often that what you need, or even, depending on your code, before you need it.